# Custom module gives 404

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

i wrote a custom module for drupal 7, placed the folder and needed files under /sites/all/modules/module_name and enabled via the backend. This is my hook_menu function;

```
function blog_contact_settings_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items["blog_contact/send_to_all"] = array(
        "title"=>"Mail all bloggers",
        "page callback"=>"drupal_get_form",
        "page arguments"=>array("blog_contact_page"),
        "access arguments"=>array("access content")
    );
    $items["blog_contact/send_to_one"] = array(
        "page_callback"=>"single_blogger_contact",
        "access_arguments"=>array("access content"),
        "type"=>MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    return $items;
}
```

My blog contactpage is suppoused to return a page with form but when i go to the `/?q=blog_contact/send_to_all`, it gives a 404. why happens that you little Einsteins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try clearing cache (Admin > Config > Development > Performance > Clear all caches).
- Does your blog_contact_page function return a form array ?
- According to your function name, your module's machine name should be "blog_contact_settings". Nothing else will work.
- You can check if your function gets called by adding some snippet like the one below to your hook_menu function.

  drupal_set_message('Hook menu function fired!');

Comment: shame on me. the module is called blog_contact, i've added the settings accidently. thanks for pointing the point that was standing front of my nose and sorry for my dumbness.